# c# directory tree search

Tags: c#, search, directory

I have to do a directory search and map it to the ui as a tree structure. I will explain my problem with the following structure

Root directory has --> [dir1] [dir2] [dir3].....[nth dir] (Note there will be only directories and no files)

[dir1] has --> [dir1a] [dir1b] [dir1c]....[nth dir1] (Note there will be only directories and no files)

[dir1a] has --> [1dir] [2dir] [3dir] (Not there will be only directories and no files)

[1dir] has --> some files and directories

so what I need here is the name of the directories till the directory that has files in it

In the above case that would be dir1/dir1a/1dir

I want to scan all the directories that only has directories in it and no files. I need the full path to the directories that has files in it.

I have tried the directory.enumeratedirectories and directoryinfo in a foreach but i think i might be going on the wrong path.

Any ideas how can I scan all the directories and get path to the directory that has files in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void FindDirectoriesWithFiles(List<string> paths, DirectoryInfo workingDir)
{
    // if this directory has files in it, add its path to the list.
    if (workingDir.GetFiles().Length > 0)
    {
        paths.Add(workingDir.FullName);
    }
    else
    {
        // Else, this directory has no files, so iterate through its children.
        foreach (var childDir in workingDir.GetDirectories())
        {
            FindDirectoriesWithFiles(paths, childDir);
        }
    }
}
```

Invoke the method above as follows:

```
var paths = new List<string>();
FindDirectoriesWithFiles(paths, new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\"));
// 'paths' now contains the folders you're looking for.
```

Note that this solution stops searching subfolders of folders that contain files.  For example, if `C:\Dir1\Dir1a\Dir1b` has files in it, but it also has subfolders in it (e.g. `C:\Dir1\Dir1a\Dir1b\Dir1c`), those subfolders (`Dir1c` in this example) would not be searched.